# Eclipse MyFirstApp Android (build.version.sdk.int)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build

I have followed the [MyFirstApp tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) line by line, but I must have skipped something, because in my onCreate method in the DisplayMessageActivity file, I get an error that I can't figure out. Here is the code in question (I tried copying it from the android website into Eclipse, but that didn't change anything):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
}
```

The line `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){` gets an error that Eclipse says "Build cannot be resolved to a variable". I was not able to figure out what that meant after googling it. I would appreciate any help on MyFirstApp, Thank you.

Comment: Do `CTRL+SHIFT+O` and see if that fixes the problem. The imports are probably not all there.

Comment: did you import `Built` related imports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try importing android.os.Build.

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know how `CTRL+SHIFT+O` didn't catch that. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The android tutorial is assuming you're using sdk version 3.0 or later. The variable HONEYCOMB won't exist if you're using an earlier version of the sdk.

Go into android sdk manager in eclipse and download a newer version if you need to use the newer functions in Honeycomb or later.